# Visual Studio Property Sheets Automatic Inclusion

Tags: visual-studio-2010, dependency-properties

To simplify, suppose I have a situation where I have written two libraries, Lib1 and Lib2.  Each library has one configuration: static (.lib) release Win32 (/MD).  Each library has a property sheet (include_lib1.props and include_lib2.props, respectively).  The property sheet for a given library:

- Exports the path to the generated .lib under Library Directories
- Exports the path to the library's source under Include Directories
- Adds the name of the generated .lib to the linker's input requirements.

---

Dependencies:

- Lib1 has no dependencies (i.e., it just includes Microsoft.Cpp.Win32.user).
- Lib2 has one dependency: Lib1 (i.e., Lib2 includes both Microsoft.Cpp.Win32.user and include_lib1.props).

---

Now I want to write an application.  Ostensibly, it depends only on Lib2--but since Lib2 was built using Lib1, the application wants *both* Lib1.props and Lib2.props* (i.e., it tries to link with Lib1.lib, and fails since Lib1's property sheet isn't there to say where to find it).

My question is: is there a way to make it so that when I include include_lib2.props, it automatically also includes include_lib1.props--or do something equivalent?

---

*This by itself is curious--the libraries are built with /MD, so could that be it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer seems to be to just add one property sheet *into* another.  Right-clicking on the property sheet allows you to add an existing one.

This very nicely solves the problem in a modular, clean fashion.  The altered property sheet can be used in multiple places.  Adding it to a new project recursively adds the depending property sheets, which can be viewed in the property pages.